# Critical Sections and return values in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, return-value, critical-section

In attempting to create a thread-safe container class from scratch, I've run into the problem of returning values from access methods. For example in Windows:

```
myNode getSomeData( )
{
  EnterCriticalSection(& myCritSec);
  myNode retobj;
  // fill retobj with data from structure
  LeaveCriticalSection(& myCritSec);
  return retobj;
}
```

Now I suppose that this type of method is not at all thread-safe because after the code releases the critical section another thread is able to come along and immediately overwrite `retobj` before the first thread returns. So what is an elegant way to return `retobj` to the caller in a thread-safe manner?

Comment: But retobj is stored on the stack? Unless it's declared 'static' you should have no problems with the copied data being overwritten.

Comment: Unless something odd is happening, `retobj` should be on the stack, and each thread should have its own stack. Race conditions of this sort are more common when you're working with pre-allocated memory and have to lock access to prevent sharing.

Comment: @inface, ok good point, so as long as the return value is stored on the stack I'm good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's thread-safe because each thread has it's own stack, and that's where `retobj` is.

However, it's certainly not exception-safe. Wrap the critical section in a RAII-style object would help that. Something like...

```
class CriticalLock : boost::noncopyable {
  CriticalSection &section;

public:
  CriticalLock(CriticalSection &cs) : section(cs)
  {
    EnterCriticalSection(section);
  }

  ~CriticalLock()
  {
    LeaveCriticalSection(section);
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
myNode getSomeData( )
{
  CriticalLock  lock(myCritSec);  // automatically released.
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is C++, and `retobj` has automatic storage type, so it's stored on the stack.

Every thread has its own stack, so another thread cannot clobber the value of `retobj` before it is returned.